# Setting a local style for an adorner

Tags: wpf, adorner

I have an adorner which should be placed beside it's adorned element. Depening on the value of the custom `Position` dependency property the adorner appears at the left or right side of the element.

I want to use a style to set the value of the `Position` property. But I can only do this if I add the style to the resources of the top-level control. If I place the style inside the resources of any child element it shows no effect.

Is there a way that I can set the adorner style on a per-element basis like in the following example?

```xaml
<Window x:Class="StyledAdorner.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StyledAdorner">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="local:MyAdorner">
            <Setter Property="Position" Value="Right" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Adorn me!" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15" />
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="AddAdorner" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button />
        <Button>
            <Button.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="local:MyAdorner">
                    <!-- This setter has no effect! -->
                    <Setter Property="Position" Value="Left" />
                </Style>
            </Button.Resources>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The only solution I can image is to scan the adorned element's resources for an adorner style. If there is one then check if there is a setter for the `Position` property and use this value. But that looks like a really dirty hack...

---

- Code for `AddAdorner` handler that creates the adorner:

```csharp
private void AddAdorner(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    new MyAdorner((UIElement)sender);
}
```

- Constructor for `MyAdorner`

```csharp
private Path _indicator = new Path { /* details omitted */ };

public MyAdorner(UIElement adornedElement) : base(adornedElement)
{
    AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(AdornedElement).Add(this);
    AddVisualChild(_indicator);
    InvalidateMeasure();
    InvalidateArrange();
}
```

Comment: Is the adorner a child of the `Button`? If not, your style inside `<Button.Resources>` won't apply. How do you add the adorner?

Comment: The adorner adorns the button thus it is not a child of the button. But even if I place the style inside the ```StackPanel``` it won't be applied to the adorner. I assume that this happens because the adorner is added into the adorner layer and not into the content presenter of the window...
I added the code section in my question.

Comment: So why don't you just set the `Position` property of the adorner programmatically when you add it?

Comment: I could do so but position is a design-related property that I would like to set by styling and not by code. With the solution provided above I am able to define a global (application wide) style for the position. If I want to change it I only have to change the style and not each constructor call of ```MyAdorner```. Maybe I am going to use an additional attached property in ```MyAdorner``` to override the position for a specific element...

Comment: Set the default value of the property if you want to define it application-wide? Or move the `Style` to `App.xaml`?

Comment: In my "real-world" scenario ```MyAdorner``` is implemented in a separated utility solution that is supplied as a NuGet-package to my application solutions. Thus, changing the default value of ```Position``` is not feasible because it would change the position for *all* projects that use this package. So the default adorner position is defined in the global style set for each project. For the rare cases where I cannot use the default position I have to use one of the workarounds (local style or attached property) to override the position. I tend to implement the latter.

Comment: Then it makes perfect sense to just set the property when you add the adorner, doesn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248229/discussion-between-matumba-and-mm8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem by turning the `Position` property into an attached property:

```csharp
public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "Position",
    typeof(AdornerPosition),
    typeof(MyAdorner),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(AdornerPosition.Right, UpdateAdornerLayerLayout));
```

Now, I just have to set the desired value on the adorned element:

```xaml
<Button local:MyAdorner.Position="Left">
```

The property is evaluated in adorner`s `ArrangeOverride` method when the position for the adorner is calculated.

Note that the `UpdateAdornerLayerLayout` property changed callback is neccessary to force a layout update for the adorner layer when the property changes:

```csharp
private static void UpdateAdornerLayerLayout(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (d is UIElement element)
    {
        var layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(element);
        layer?.Update();
    }
}
```